# Swap nested specific item in map finding by key value, the position in map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

We have a cursor or atom map with this example data:

```
    #<Cursor: [:customer] {:name Diego Peña, 

    :addresses [{:id 23, :province Madrid, :country 1, :descripcion aaeeeeeeee iii oooo4444, :locality Gali gali, :country_name SPAIN, :direccion Street Cierva, :id 3, :postalcode 30203, :principal true, :customer 17} 

{:id 35, :province Madrid, :country nil, :descripcion yyy lalala3, :locality Lalala, :direccion calle Maria 3 , :postalcode 333, :principal false, :customer 17} 

{:id 6, :province Madrid, :country 2, :descripcion otra direccioncita444, :locality Leleele, :country_name SPAIN, :direccion Direccion calle Ooo, :postalcode 1236, :main false, :customer 17} 

{:id 27, :province Madrid, :country 1, :descripcion grandisima, :locality Alcantarilla, :country_name SPAIN, :direccion C/ 3 Mayo, :postalcode 3001, :main false, :customer 17}

]}>
```

I need to change the values of a searched address by id. I have managed to locate the address by the value of the id:

```
(defn get-address [pk]
   (->> @db/customer :addresses (filter #(= (int pk) (int (:id %)))) first)
)
```

I can change all addresses with this: `:ok #(swap! db/customer assoc-in [:addresses] %)})`. I need to change data for a **specific address** from the API response.

I am close to getting it, but with this approach I am missing the position or the index of the item: `#(swap! db/client assoc-in [:addresses ¿position or index in map?] %)` we have the id of item address.

Perhaps this approach is wrong, a better one?

Comment: What is the `Cursor`?  Also, please print using `prn` instead of `println` to preserve double-quotes around strings in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [assoc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc), [assoc-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in), [update](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update), and [update-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) functions work also on vectors. In Clojure, vectors are associative data structures where the key is the numeric index (`O..n`) and the value is the item at position `n`.

So you can do:

```clj
(assoc [:a :b :c] 1 :new-value)
;;      ^  ^  ^
;;      0  1  2
;; => [:a :new-value :c]
```

Based on your example, you will need this:

```clj
(defn address-index-by-id
  "Take an `address` map and look it up by `:id` in the `addresses` list.
   Return the numeric index where it was found, nil if not found."
  [address addresses]
  (->> (map-indexed vector addresses) 
       ;; produce a seq `([0 val-at-index-0] … [n val-at-index-n])`
       (filter (fn [[_index {:keys [id]}]] (= id  (:id address)))) ;; filter by id
       (ffirst) ;; get the index of the first match
       ))

(defn set-address
  "Take a `customer` map and an `address` map. Will put the `address` in the
  customer's addresses list. If an address with the same :id key is already
  present in this list, it will be overwritten."
  [customer address]
  (if-let [existing-index (address-index-by-id address (:addresses customer))]
    (assoc-in customer [:addresses existing-index] address)
    (update customer :addresses conj address)))
```

Usage:

```clj
(set-address {:name      "Diego Peña"
              :addresses []}
             {:id       1
              :province "Madrid"})
;; => {:name "Diego Peña", :addresses [{:id 1, :province "Madrid"}]}

(-> {:name      "Diego Peña"
     :addresses [{:id       1
                  :province "Madrid"
                  :main     true}
                 {:id       2
                  :province "Barcelona"
                  :main     false}]}
    (set-address {:id       2
                  :province "Barcelona"
                  :main     true})
    (set-address {:id       1
                  :province "Madrid"
                  :main     false}))
;; => {:name "Diego Peña", :addresses [{:id 1, :province "Madrid", :main false} {:id 2, :province "Barcelona", :main true}]}

;; And of course if your `customer` is stored in an Atom:
(swap! customer set-address {:id 1, :province "Madrid", :main true})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pulling data out of a database of some kind. If so, you should let the DB search for the ID in question.  You can then read or update that record.

If you really need to do it in Clojure, you can search for the desired customer map using the [tupelo.forest library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc).  Here is an example with your data:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.forest :as tf]))

(def customer
  {:name "Diego Peña",
   :addresses
         [{:id           23
           :province     "Madrid"
           :country      1
           :descripcion  " aaeeeeeeee iii oooo4444"
           :locality     "Gali gali"
           :country_name "SPAIN"
           :direccion    "Street Cierva"
           :postalcode   30203
           :principal    true
           }
          {:id          35
           :province    "Madrid"
           :country     nil
           :descripcion "yyy lalala3"
           :locality    "Lalala"
           :direccion   "calle Maria 3"
           :postalcode  333
           :principal   false
           :customer    17}
          {:id           6
           :province     "Madrid"
           :country      2
           :descripcion  "otra direccioncita444"
           :locality     "Leleele"
           :country_name "SPAIN"
           :direccion    "Direccion calle Ooo"
           :postalcode   1236
           :main         false
           :customer     17}
          {:id           27
           :province     "Madrid"
           :country      1
           :descripcion  "grandisima"
           :locality     "Alcantarilla"
           :country_name "SPAIN"
           :direccion    "C / 3 Mayo"
           :postalcode   3001
           :main         false
           :customer     17}
          ]})
```

and some code to find customer with :id 35

```
(dotest
  (tf/with-forest (tf/new-forest)
    (let [root-hid        (tf/add-tree-edn customer)
          cust-num        35
          paths-found     (tf/find-paths root-hid [:**
                                                   {:tag :tupelo.forest/entry, :tupelo.forest/key :id}
                                                   {:tupelo.forest/value cust-num}])
          cust-path-rev   (reverse (last paths-found))
          cust-entity-hid (xthird cust-path-rev)
          ]

      (is= (tf/hid->bush (xfirst cust-path-rev)) [#:tupelo.forest{:value 35, :index nil}])

      (is= (tf/hid->tree cust-entity-hid)
        {:tag                 :tupelo.forest/entity,
         :tupelo.forest/index 1,
         :tupelo.forest/kids  [{:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :locality,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value "Lalala", :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :customer,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value 17, :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :descripcion,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value "yyy lalala3", :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :direccion,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value "calle Maria 3", :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :id,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value 35, :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :postalcode,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value 333, :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :principal,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value false, :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :province,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value "Madrid", :index nil}]}
                               {:tag                :tupelo.forest/entry,
                                :tupelo.forest/key  :country,
                                :tupelo.forest/kids [#:tupelo.forest{:kids [], :value nil, :index nil}]}]})
```

You can convert the data from the internal tree format back into EDN data:

```
      (is= (tf/hid->edn cust-entity-hid)
        {:locality    "Lalala",
         :customer    17,
         :descripcion "yyy lalala3",
         :direccion   "calle Maria 3",
         :id          35,
         :postalcode  333,
         :principal   false,
         :province    "Madrid",
         :country     nil})

      )))
```

You never really said how you want to change the data.  Again, it would probably be best to do this with the DB rather than changing Clojure data structures.

---

### Update

Another option is to use a recursive walk like `clojure.walk/postwalk` or the enhanced `tupelo.core/walk-with-parents`.  Example to uppercase street name for cust ID #35

```
(dotest
  (let [modified (t/walk-with-parents customer
                   {:enter (fn [parents item]
                             (with-nil-default item
                               (when (and (map? item)
                                       (t/submap? {:id 35} item))
                                 (spyx-pretty item)
                                 (update item :direccion str/upper-case))))})]
    (is= modified {:name "Diego Peña",
                   :addresses
                         [{:locality     "Gali gali",
                           :descripcion  " aaeeeeeeee iii oooo4444",
                           :country_name "SPAIN",
                           :direccion    "Street Cierva",
                           :id           23,
                           :postalcode   30203,
                           :principal    true,
                           :province     "Madrid",
                           :country      1}
                          {:locality    "Lalala",
                           :customer    17,
                           :descripcion "yyy lalala3",
                           :direccion   "CALLE MARIA 3",
                           :id          35,
                           :postalcode  333,
                           :principal   false,
                           :province    "Madrid",
                           :country     nil}
                          {:locality     "Leleele",
                           :customer     17,
                           :descripcion  "otra direccioncita444",
                           :country_name "SPAIN",
                           :direccion    "Direccion calle Ooo",
                           :id           6,
                           :postalcode   1236,
                           :main         false,
                           :province     "Madrid",
                           :country      2}
                          {:locality     "Alcantarilla",
                           :customer     17,
                           :descripcion  "grandisima",
                           :country_name "SPAIN",
                           :direccion    "C / 3 Mayo",
                           :id           27,
                           :postalcode   3001,
                           :main         false,
                           :province     "Madrid",
                           :country      1}]})))
```